# Highcharts afterAnimate in combination with xAxis max

Tags: highcharts

We are developing some charts using Highcharts.
And we are using the `series.events.afterAnimate` in combination with an `xAxis.max` value.

But when we have for example points from Januari until September, but with an xAxis.max value until December the `afterAnimate` function is called when it reached December we guess..

But we would like have a callback when all the valid points are drawn, and not we it reaches its max value...

is this possible?

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue in online code editor like jsfiddle?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel

https://jsfiddle.net/3w8o0s6r/4/

As you can see the first chart has less points then the second chart.. 
But the label gets drawn on the same time.. 

This means the `afterAnimate` is called when all points are checked. But I would like to have a callback when all the x values are drawn even when there are less then the max xAxis value..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the clipPath width is by default equal width of the plot area. To change it you can overwrite `Highcharts.Series.animate` method and set clipPath width equal width of the particular series.

**EDIT:**

Also, note that when the width of the clipPath is shorter and the duration of the animation is the same the animation will be much slower. To make it look better the time has to be shortened - it can be calculated depending on series width and updated in chart `load` event.

Check demo and code posted below:

**Code:**

```js
(function(H) {
 H.Series.prototype.animate = function(init) {
    var series = this,
      chart = series.chart,
      clipRect,
      animation = H.animObject(series.options.animation),
      sharedClipKey;
      

    // Initialize the animation. Set up the clipping rectangle.
    if (init) {

      series.setClip(animation);

      // Run the animation
    } else {
    
      sharedClipKey = this.sharedClipKey;
      clipRect = chart[sharedClipKey];
      if (clipRect) {
        clipRect.animate({
          width: series.group.getBBox().width,
          x: 0
        }, animation);
      }
      if (chart[sharedClipKey + 'm']) {
        chart[sharedClipKey + 'm'].animate({
          width: chart.plotSizeX + 99,
          x: 0
        }, animation);
      }

      // Delete this function to allow it only once
      series.animate = null;

    }
  }
})(Highcharts);

Highcharts.setOptions({
 chart: {
   events: {
     load: function() {
       var chart = this,
          series = chart.series[0],
            seriesWidth = series.graph.getBBox().width,
            duration = (seriesWidth / chart.plotWidth) * series.options.animation.duration;
        
        chart.series[0].update({
         animation: {
           duration: duration
          }
        });
      }
    }  
  },
  plotOptions: {
   series: {
     animation: {
       duration: 2000
      }
    }
  }
});


Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Chart with half data but with max data'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'A label should appear when all points are drawn'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    min: Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1),
    max: Date.UTC(2019, 11, 31),
    tickInterval: 2592000000, // month
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        afterAnimate: function() {
          this.chart.renderer.label(this.name + ' has appeared', 100, 70)
            .attr({
              padding: 10,
              fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            })
            .css({
              color: 'white'
            })
            .add();
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1),
        y: 29.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 1, 1),
        y: 139.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 2, 1),
        y: 59.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 3, 1),
        y: 19.9
      },
    ]
  }]
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
  title: {
    text: 'Chart with full data'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'A label should appear on the plot area after animate'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    min: Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1),
    max: Date.UTC(2019, 11, 31),
    tickInterval: 2592000000, // month
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        afterAnimate: function() {
          this.chart.renderer.label(this.name + ' has appeared', 100, 70)
            .attr({
              padding: 10,
              fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            })
            .css({
              color: 'white'
            })
            .add();
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1),
        y: 29.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 1, 1),
        y: 139.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 2, 1),
        y: 59.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 3, 1),
        y: 19.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 4, 1),
        y: 29.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 5, 1),
        y: 139.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 6, 1),
        y: 59.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 7, 1),
        y: 19.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 8, 1),
        y: 29.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 9, 1),
        y: 139.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 10, 1),
        y: 59.9
      },
      {
        x: Date.UTC(2019, 11, 1),
        y: 19.9
      },

    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<div id="container2" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gj7eqkv8/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: But you also set a faster animation duration on the first chart?